# Remove path in url header and Rewrite URL using AWS ALB

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

Rewrite URL in AWS ALB by removing header

I have a ingress rule defined in k8s cluster(running on AWS EKS Cluster) using ALB ad ingress-controller;

```
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: analytics-dev
  namespace: analytics-dev
  labels:
    app: analytics-dev
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
    merge.ingress.kubernetes.io/config: analytics
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/certificate-arn: arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:570346789076:certificate/43d3b1b6-ae3f-49b8-b115-f379a5c6789b
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports: '[{"HTTP": 80}, {"HTTPS":443}]'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: HTTPS
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/actions.ssl-redirect: '{"Type": "redirect", "RedirectConfig": { "Protocol": "HTTPS", "Port": "443", "StatusCode": "HTTP_301"}}'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
spec:
  rules:
    - host: portal.analytics-dev.io
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /api
            backend:
              serviceName: play-server
              servicePort: 9443
          - path: /*
            backend:
              serviceName: ssl-redirect
              servicePort: use-annotation
          - path: /*
            backend:
              serviceName: node-server
              servicePort: 443
```

when user tries to access url as **https://portal.analytics-dev.io/api** it should redirect the request to play-server service running on k8s cluster by removing /api from the URL-path; How can I get remove /api from url and redirect to play-server SERVICE

Comment: Don't give path, directly mention backend: 
          - backend:
              serviceName: play-server
              servicePort: 9443
          - path: /*
            backend:
              serviceName: ssl-redirect
              servicePort: use-annotation
          - path: /*
            backend:
              serviceName: node-server
              servicePort: 443

Comment: It didnt work for me; so I have requested our dev team to expose the route /api on the app. Thanks for looking into this